# SQL Server 2008 R2 : Present Trip Data in a different Way

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a some trip data that I want to split off in a specfic way as follows.

Here's the data as

```
NodeId  dNodeid StartTripUTC            EndTripUTC              TripDistance
3737    3738    2016-04-11 12:45:44.000 2016-04-11 13:47:57.000     9987
3737    3738    2016-04-11 12:54:00.000 2016-04-11 13:12:00.000     NULL
3737    3738    2016-04-11 13:22:00.000 2016-04-11 13:42:00.000     NULL
```

The row(s) where the TripDistance is NULL are sub Trips, if you like, of the complete trip which is shown as the row where the TripDistance IS NOT NULL.

I want to present it like so

```
NodeId  dNodeid StartTripUTC            EndTripUTC              TripDistance
3737    3738    2016-04-11 12:45:44.000 2016-04-11 12:54:00.000     9987
3737    3738    2016-04-11 13:12:00.000 2016-04-11 13:22:00.000     NULL
3737    3738    2016-04-11 13:42:00.000 2016-04-11 13:47:57.000     NULL
```

So the "EndTripUTC" from the first row becomes the "EndTripUTC" of the last row.
The "StartTripUTC" from row 2 becomes the "EndTripUTC" of the first row.
And so on and so forth.

Your help is much appreciated.

Here's some sample data.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BreakdownTrips') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #BreakdownTrips
CREATE TABLE #BreakdownTrips(
        NodeId          INT
    ,dNodeid        INT
    ,StartTripUTC   DATETIME
    ,EndTripUTC     DATETIME
    ,TripDistance   INT
)

INSERT INTO #BreakdownTrips(
        NodeId
    ,dNodeid
    ,StartTripUTC
    ,EndTripUTC
    ,TripDistance
)
VALUES
    ( 3737,3738,'2016-04-11 12:45:44.000','2016-04-11 13:47:57.000',9987 )
,( 3737,3738,'2016-04-11 12:54:00.000','2016-04-11 13:12:00.000',NULL )
,( 3737,3738,'2016-04-11 13:22:00.000','2016-04-11 13:42:00.000',NULL )
,( 3999,923,'2016-04-11 10:30:52.000','2016-04-11 10:46:30.000',0 )
,( 3999,923,'2016-04-11 10:30:52.500','2016-04-11 10:46:00.000',NULL )
,( 4006,1010,'2016-04-14 13:36:30.000','2016-04-14 14:25:49.000',39 )
,( 4006,1010,'2016-04-14 13:36:30.000','2016-04-14 14:12:00.000',NULL )
,( 4006,1010,'2016-04-14 14:14:00.000','2016-04-14 14:24:00.000',NULL )


DROP TABLE #BreakdownTrips
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the trick.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BreakdownTripsTemp') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #BreakdownTripsTemp

select rownum = row_number() over
(
    partition by x.NodeId, x.dNodeid
    order by x.NodeId, x.dNodeid, x.TripUTC, x.TripDistance desc
), x.*
into #BreakdownTripsTemp
from 
(
    select a.NodeId, a.dNodeid, a.StartTripUTC as 'TripUTC', a.TripDistance
    from #BreakdownTrips a

    union 

    select  a.NodeId, a.dNodeid, a.EndTripUTC as 'TripUTC', NULL
    from #BreakdownTrips a
) x

select a.NodeId, a.dNodeid, a.TripUTC as 'StartTripUTC', b.TripUTC as 'EndTripUTC', a.TripDistance 
from #BreakdownTripsTemp a
inner join #BreakdownTripsTemp b on a.NodeId = b.NodeId 
                                and a.dNodeid = b.dNodeid 
                                and a.rownum = (b.rownum - 1) -- join odd and even rows
where (a.rownum % 2) = 1 -- get the odd rows
order by a.NodeId, a.dNodeid, a.rownum
```

Basically I union all the dates within a NodeId and dNodeid combination together, apply row numbers within the partition of NodeId and dNodeid and put the results in a temp table. To bring it together I query the odd row numbers from the temp table to get all of the data except for the EndTripUTC and inner join to the even rows of the temp table to get the EndTripUTC.

```
NodeId      dNodeid     StartTripUTC            EndTripUTC              TripDistance
----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------
3737        3738        2016-04-11 12:45:44.000 2016-04-11 12:54:00.000 9987
3737        3738        2016-04-11 13:12:00.000 2016-04-11 13:22:00.000 NULL
3737        3738        2016-04-11 13:42:00.000 2016-04-11 13:47:57.000 NULL
3999        923         2016-04-11 10:30:52.000 2016-04-11 10:30:52.500 0
3999        923         2016-04-11 10:46:00.000 2016-04-11 10:46:30.000 NULL
4006        1010        2016-04-14 13:36:30.000 2016-04-14 13:36:30.000 39
4006        1010        2016-04-14 14:12:00.000 2016-04-14 14:14:00.000 NULL
4006        1010        2016-04-14 14:24:00.000 2016-04-14 14:25:49.000 NULL
```

Enjoy,

Noel

Comment: That's great. Thank you